# how to load global variables from ajax get with promisses

Tags: javascript, ajax, loading

I am getting data to global variables in the most dummy way. At the moment:

```
var tranlationJson =
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "translation.xml",
     contentType: "text/xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function (dataSource) {            
        tranlationJson=ToJasonParser(dataSource);
     }
  });
```

And i want to modify it to use promisses. The issue is that the code which follows is using third party js files so my code is like

```
<script
<script

var tranlationJson  = $.ajax({ ...

<script 111
<script 222
```

and script 111 and 222 contain custom libraties which will be using the translationJson in it. So how can i ensure that the translationJson will be filled before loading the scripts?

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd part… at all.

Comment: As you have it currently laid out, you cannot ensure the variable is set. To achieve what you want, you would have to construct the later script tags inside the success callback of the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is global variable that you can reach from any of your scripts: `window`. Instead of your `var translationJson = $.ajax({...` you can do `window.translationJson = $.ajax({...`. But there are two important things here:

First is you don't know what will come first: ajax request finished or some of your script already ask for your variable. The solution is to bind all depending of your variable scripts running to `$.ajax({ success:` callback. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "translation.xml",
         contentType: "text/xml",
         dataType: "xml",
         success: function (dataSource) {            
            tranlationJson=ToJasonParser(dataSource);
            someScriptRun(); /* here you run some depending on your variable script */
         }
    });
```

Another way is to check for variable in all of dependant scripts like this:

```
var periodicalAttemptToRunScriptDependant = setInterval( function(){
  if( 'object' == typeof window.translationJson ){
    someScriptRun(); /* here you run some depending on your variable script */
    clearInterval( periodicalAttemptToRunScriptDependant );
  }
}, 1000 );
```

Second: in your example any request for a variable will cause ajax request, because it is not a variable actually but function. Try to change your code to:

```
var tranlationJson;
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "translation.xml",
     contentType: "text/xml",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function (dataSource) {            
        tranlationJson = ToJasonParser(dataSource);
     }
});
```

Comment: Would it be good approach to use:
success: function (dataSource) {            
        tranlationJson = ToJasonParser(dataSource);

$.getScript("test.js");
     }
 And load 2-3 scripts in it?

Comment: If you only start download script after ajax call finished – it can take a bit more time than if you downloaded all of scripts almost simultaneously but defined a sequence of run the way I suggested. Thus getScript will work but a bit longer.